# How to debug a "openvswitch" like kernel modules program in a virtual machine environment?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, openvswitch

I am working on a project like "openvswitch" --- a linux kernel modules that interfaces with
various network interface cards.

You can bind some network interfaces (like eth0, eth1) to the module, and then packet received from the interfaces will be handled by the kernel module (it may modified the packet header and send the packet from another binding interface).

In a virtual machine environment, I can easily do the development work (kernel space programming often crash the machine) but I can hardly do the testing work. It is difficulty to
send a specific packet to the vm's specific interface. Is there any easy way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a traffic generation tool like [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) on your hypervisor to send traffic to the virtual NICs that are attached to your VM. With qemu/libvirt these interfaces normally come up as "vnet0", "vnet1", etc.

Do not use bridges, but send traffic directly to the vnic. Linux bridges are good at forwarding IP traffic but will not let every ethernet frame go through unmodified.